# Github, making an Github api request on behalf of my customer

Tags: php, git, github

I am making a webapp in PHP where my customers can add their github account (just one time) and they can see the PULL request of their organization/repo in my web app.

The github pull request api document says that to consume the pull request api one needs to be an owner. By owner I am assuming that the person needs to be the admin of his github account and not just a contributor.

I do not understand how geckoboard.com handles this. When I login into my geckoboard account and i add github service with my githhub account, i can see my repo pull request (for which i am just a contributor)

So I have the following questions here:

1. How do I make a github api request to fetch pull request details of my customer's repo?
2. Is there anyway I can fetch my customer's pull request details of his repo even if he is not the owner and just a contributor?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user to give you his GitHub access to your application. Check the [OAuth Web Flow for the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow).

> Is there anyway I can fetch my customer's pull request details of his repo even if he is not the owner and just a contributor?

Yes: Pull requests are available if the user has write access to the repository, regardless if he is an owner or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I agree I need to ask the user to give me his github access via OAuth but I cannot ask him everytime I run my cron to fetch his pull request details, what do I need to do so that once i got his github access my automated script can fetch his pull request details every hour?